# Why ist TRIANGLE_LIST with scale.x = 0.001 not shown?

Tags: ros, rviz, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I want to draw some triangles in RVIZ via TRIANGLE_LIST and have problems to understand the scale in this case. I had the size set to

```
marker.scale.x = marker.scale.y = 0.001;
marker.scale.z = 1;
```

from visualizing another type. A marker with this scale was not drawn in RVIZ (also no warning was generated). It took me some time to find this error and my triangles are rendered nicely if I set the scale to [1,1,1]. Can someone tell me why this is implemented in this way? Shouldn't the scale be ignored completely?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189865/why-ist-triangle_list-with-scale.x-=-0.001-not-shown?/) by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3519 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-12**:
0.001 is 0.1 cm which is very small, you can zoom out more to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why would you want the scale to be ignored? That doesn't seem to make sense. Set it to 1, if you want to draw the triangles  exactly as you did. Scale being ignored would be coutnerintuitive as it takes a feature away. If you set the scale to 0.001 it's drawn at a 1/1000th size. It is not surprising that this is not visible unless you zoom in.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1